# neo4j java runtime warning

Tags: neo4j, java

In a new install, I'm getting the following warning on OSX 10.8.3, after installing and confirming that JAVA 7 is the default:

```
MacBook-Pro:neo4j-community-1.9 roy$ bin/neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R)
Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [1959]... waiting for server to be ready.... OK.
Go to http://localhost:7474/webadmin/ for administration interface.
```

I am unable to CREATE nodes, or anything else at this time.
Any pointers most appreciated!

Comment: This is most likely because you are using a JDK other then the official package from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I edited the utils file in the bin folder of Neo4j by changing the JAVA_HOME to reflect the latest Java installed and the JAVACMD variable to $JAVA_HOME/Commands/java instead of $JAVA_HOME/bin/java. After this I no longer got the unsupported Java version warning.